# How to vertical align input box

Tags: vertical-alignment

I have a 6 input box look like:

[image]

How can I change to look like:

[image]

A demo at http://jsfiddle.net/N5dkH/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way is to put them in a table.
That will give you some extra code but its the simplest way to do it.
I believe you can also use form width & use float: right property

Answer (score 1):

That is horizontal, not vertical, alignment.

I consider that to be a table of data and use the `<table>` and `<td>` tags to set it up.